# Find inside zeros in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi can anyone help me find inside zeros using Java.
for example:

input: 1205700000 return: 1
--> you stripped the trailing zeros out
--> 12057 = now there's only 1 zero left, which is the answer

input: 1001 return: 2
--> there are no trailing zero and there are 2 inside zeros

input: 1000 return: 0
--> stripped trailing zero out = 1
--> no zero left inside so answer is 0

Ps. Is there any built-in for 'stripping' trailing zeros?

Thanks =D

Comment: Key is using integer divide and remainder

Comment: 1. So, for 102003 you want to get 3, right?
2. Can you add your code? I suppose that you tried something ... 3. IntelliJ is not a good tag. You can use Notepad or vim. 4. You can try to replace the trailing zeros (where the key word is "replace"), then to count the other zeros.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  Without know what you have done there is no way to guess what you need to know to finish this.

Comment: First step would seem to specify the input: is it a _number_, or is it a string of characters? If it is a _number_: what _is_ a `zero`? What type is returned, and what shall be `return:` for, e.g., `102003` (engineer)?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this in Java 8 is

```
String str = 
int longest = Stream.of(str.replaceAll("0+$", "").split("[^0]+"))
                     .mapToInt(String::length)
                     .max().getAsInt();
```

This will be 0 if there is no `0`.

Comment: I think he wants `sum()` instead of `max()`

Comment: Using `str.replaceAll("[^0]+|0+$", "").length` is not streamy enough?

Comment: @greybeard it is possible I miss read the question. I have the largest block of zeros. Your answer, could be right as it counts the total number of zeros, without trailing zeros.